# OpenSSL 0.9.8k or higher on CentOS 5?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, openssl

I need to upgrade OpenSSL on my CentOS server to 0.9.8k or higher, however the latest version in the official CentOS repositories is 0.9.8e, much too old. Is there a 3rd party repository I can use that has newer versions of OpenSSL libraries? If not, can someone provide a quick walkthrough of compiling a newer version of OpenSSL for CentOS? I need it to replace the built in version, so the walkthrough would have to explain how to create a CentOS-compatible RPM.

Comment: Why do you want to get that 0.9.8k or higher? Do you need any new feature or do you need a CVE bugfix? The latter is usually backported to 0.9.8e by RedHat. See Rilindos answer below.

Comment: Myself, I am looking for specific OpenSSL features, such as [Server Name Indication](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI). Apparently there are no OpenSSL 1.x RPMs available for EL5, so I'd simply need to compile or roll my own RPMs to install to /opt or elsewhere , and tell specific applications to use those specific OpenSSL libraries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let me guess - PCI?

What you really want is to look at Red Hat's [CVE](http://www.redhat.com/security/transparent/cve/) archives (which CentOS is based on) and verified whether the vulnerability has been fixed based on that list (most of the time, it has been). If you are using a third-party scanner that doesn't recognize your current version, look up the [OVAL](http://www.redhat.com/security/transparent/oval/) definitions to see the status of the vulnerabilities as well as whether the fixes were back ported; from there, you can map them to the current "generic" versions of your applications / libraries (in this case, OpenSSL).

Red Hat's [link](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting/) gives more details (which CentOS [reference](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-472ce8446ebcfc82ca1800f775ba0e629ac835c7)) as their backports policy. You may want to review it and save yourself the trouble of rebuilding OpenSSL.

Answer (score 8):

Be aware that RedHat backports security fixes and such to packages and only increments the package subversion number and not the versioning of the package. Since Centos comes directly from RedHat, I might expect the same from their packaging as well.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Centos 6. It has version 1.0.0 built-in. See the list of packages and RPMs here: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/i386/Packages/

But it is never a good idea to install two versions of the same software on one system.

Comment: Important to note that there is no supported "upgrade" from 5.x to 6.x. RedHat says "[Red Hat does not support in-place upgrades between any major versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/sn-upgrading-system-x86.html)".

Comment: @StefanLasiewski How bad is that! Says a proud user of Debian (and derivates) where these impediments don't exist.